# SUM of Grouped value

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have table format of mysql data like this

```
ID| FROM |  TO  | Duration(s) |
--|------|-------|-------------|
1 | Brij |Nilesh |      30     |
--|------|-------|-------------|
2 |Jaydip| Vipul |      58     |
--|------|-------|-------------|  
3 |Rajesh|Nilesh |      12     |
--|------|-------|-------------|
4 |Jaydip| vipul |      19     |
--|------|-------|-------------|
5 |Jaydip| vipul |      28     |
--|------|-------|-------------|
6 | Brij | Nilesh|      08     |
--|------|-------|-------------|
7 |vipul | Brij  |      48     |
```

So i used to get most frequent pair from data using this query

"Select FROM,TO, COUNT('FROM' & 'TO') AS howmany from table GROUP BY FROM,TO"

Which gives me result like this

```
  FROM  |   TO   |howmany|
--------|--------|-------|
  Brij  | Nilesh |   2   |
--------|--------|-------|
 Jaydip | Vipul  |   3   |
--------|--------|-------|
 Rajesh | Nilesh |   1   |
--------|--------|-------|
 vipul  | Brij   |   1   |
```

But i also want the sum of Duration In these group like

```
Brij  | Nilesh |   2   | 30 +  08 = 38
------|--------|-------|-------
Jaydip| vipul  |   3   | 58 + 19 + 28 = 105
------|--------|-------|-------
Rajesh| Nilesh |   1   | 12
------|--------|-------|-------
vipul | Brij   |   1   | 48
```

So please suggest me query for that i'm bit new to mysql so i don't know much about advance options in query . . . . .
Thanks . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM, TO, SUM(DURATION), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY FROM,TO;
```

Comment: @Jadeja_RJ Come now, surely you could have figured this one out yourself.